# Query Regarding Static Block

Tags: java

I have a question regarding this scenario

I have 2 classes
Class A and class B inside 2 different packages as follow.

```
Package test1 // first Package
public class B
{
public static int q = 10; // having one static variable
static
{
system.out.println ("test")// One static block which is printing something
}
}
```

inside 2nd package

```
Package test   
import test1.B  // Importing class B from Package test1
public class A
{
int c = B.q // reading the value q from class B
}
```

So in this case when I will execute class A the static block  that is in class B

> static  { system.out.println ("test") }

will be executed or not.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code - it's really hard to read without indentation.

Comment: Next, you can test your question very easily - just run that code (after you've fixed the fact that it won't compile with those package statements...) Is there any reason you can't do so?

Comment: @user2256009 as soon as your `B` class is loaded into JVM, static block will get executed.

Comment: I suspect you're not running exactly the same code, to be honest. Note that adding `final` before the declaration of `q` will make a big difference. You're certainly not running the code you posted, given that it wouldn't compile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static initializer block will get executed as soon as the class gets loaded into the virtual machine. Your code is accessing a static field in the class `B`, which will cause the class to be loaded and the static initializer to be executed.

It does not matter whether class `A` extends class `B` or not.

Comment: Class B does not need to be loaded until an instance of class A is created. OP has clearly not shown us all the code, so it's not clear that class B will be loaded at all (or class A, for that matter).

Comment: In that case, class B will be loaded only if an instance of A will be created, because B class is used to set non static memer of A class.

Answer (score 1):

According to [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7), static initializer will be executed, when Class is loading by the JVM. So, it means, that in your case it'll be executed no doubt, whenever you get an instance of A class.

Comment: This assumes that class B will be loaded. Without knowing more about the code, it's not clear that this will happen.

Comment: Yes, you have to get an instance of class A, but it's said, that class A will be used, suppose it means, that it'll be instantiated. Just  specified my answer. thanks.